# Determine object hierarchy of java class generated by XJC

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

I have a XSD file ( which contains complex structure ). I generated java class using XJC command.
Now I want to know which is parent class and which is child class programmatically.

Any idea or help will be highly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), more specifically the [Class.getSuperClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) method.